# onPreferenceClick losing the selector

Tags: java, android, preference

If I set a `onPreferenceClick` method without doing nothing, I can see the selector when the users tap on the Preference.

```java
@override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    // empty
}
```

But when I am trying to load a fragment when the user taps on the Preference, the selector is not showing up any more.
How can we overcome this issue?

A solution I found that works is to place the task inside a runnable, but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

```java
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ///do my task here
        }
    }, 100);
```